# What is the Point of "Import" in ES 6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

In other words, what is the difference between:

```
<!--index.html--> 
<script src="./fooFolder/lib.js"></script>
```

and

```
/*--app.js --*/
import * as lib from 'fooFolder/lib';
```

The file being accessed:

```
//------ lib.js ------
export const sqrt = Math.sqrt;
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
export function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
}
```

Is the main benefit of using the import statement that not everything is loaded immediately? But it seems that I still have to include the file references in the index, so that doesn't seem to be the case.

So, in short, what's the point (I am sure there is one, and I am completely missing it).

Comment: The point is how much easier your code is to manage. Let's say you have some file called `utils.js` which relies on another, say, `urlparams.js` - if you want to use the first one you HAVE TO include the second one. If you have 20 HTML pages you will have both in all of them. Now let's say that you make `urlparams.js` dependant on `parseurl.js`. You need to go and update every single one of the 20 pages to add that import. If you just use the `import` statement, you don't have to touch a thing aside from this one file.

Comment: Is this not relevant to single-page applications then? Since I only have index.html and a bunch of other html that gets nested in it as views? Maybe I am looking at this from the wrong angle.

Comment: Technically it's not _as_ relevant for single page app, given that you will have all your imports there anyway. However, I'd still consider modularisation an advantage. It means you can unit test your code much easier - if you want to unit test `utils.js` you will just do it, instead of having to manually importing everything it needs and then changing those imports when there is a transitive dependancy. Sure, you could just import _everything_ for the test but that still means you have to do the same for _each_ of your tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Scoping and namespaces
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)
2. Code seperation and Testing, imports allow errors to be localised, less complex to test due to limited scope
3. Compression and optimization, tools can figure out what code is or is not needed so you can focus on programming instead of dependency hunting
4. Shared libraries, common packages use less boilerplate code

Imports are a big part of good code architecture, I recommend you read something like Angular 2 architecture if you want to learn more https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html

Comment: Just for background: I understand namespacing from C# and scope from Angular 1 (and other places for both) , and am trying to understand this due to learning Angular2 right now. I still don't understand how this work on single page apps, e.g. angular 2? Don't I see EVERY piece of javascript anyway, after including it in index html? So it has advantage in testing components, but not while running the whole app? Edit: I guess I am trying to understand - including js files and index html and then including sub-components is REDUNDANT, right? For the purposes of the ng2 app?

Comment: `So it has advantage in testing components, but not while running the whole app?` well, your app will definitely be improved if you don't have useless libraries added, for example. Maybe not by much, maybe a lot but not having them will be better. However, if you don't know what your code uses, you can't really remove any import. Using the import functionality will not add any useless libraries by definition. Furthermore, you can more easily identify if you use something or not. Code bundling tools can also use that information to exclude unused modules.

Comment: It might also have direct benefit to your app, since good scoped code will let the JIT JS compiler know it can safely build it since there arent any unknown states and import order does not matter so it can do it concurently.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.